# Nesting an object in a class

Tags: c++, class, syntax-error, inner-classes

Using C++ I'm trying to nest an object of one class inside another class and I get a syntax error on line 6 of `CarpetClass.h` that says

> Error: fuction "Rectangle" is not a type name

**myclass.h**

```
class Rectangle{
private:
    double length;
    double width;
public:
    void setLength(double len){
        length = len;
    }
    void setWidth(double wid){
        width = wid;
    }
    double getLength(){
        return length;
    }
    double getWidth(){
        return width;
    }
    double getArea(){
        return length*width;
    }
};
```

**CarpetClass.h**

```
#include "myclass.h"

class Carpet{
private:
    double pricePerSqYd;
    Rectangle size;
public:
    void setPricePeryd(double p){
        pricePerSqYd = p;
    }
    void setDimensions (double len, double wid){
        size.setLength(len / 3);
        size.setWidth(wid / 3);
    }
    double getTotalPrice(){
        return (size.getArea*pricePerSqYd);
    }
};
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CarpetClass.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Carpet purchase;
    double pricePerYd;
    double length;
    double width;

    cout << "Room length in feet: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << "Room width in feet: ";
    cin >> width;
    cout << "Carpet price per sq. yard: ";
    cin >> pricePerYd;
    purchase.setDimensions(length, width);
    purchase.setPricePeryd(pricePerYd);
    cout << "\nThe total price of my new " << length << "x" << width << " carpet is $" << purchase.getTotalPrice() << endl;
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting an error I copied example code right out of my text book. I have tried putting both classes in my cpp file and also putting them both in the same header file. Neither of those solutions worked. Please help me understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: You should look into the difference between .h and .cpp files.

Comment: The only problem I see is `size.getArea*pricePerSqYd` should be `size.getArea()*pricePerSqYd`, beyond that everything should compile just fine. You don't have `myclass.h` set to include `CarpetClass.h` do you?

Comment: I doubt very much that your compiler uses the word "fuction" in its error message. Please post the actual error message in full.

Comment: ..or there is some other declaration of Rectangle in your project. Do the two files comprise the whole project?

Comment: When I hover my mouse over Rectangle it reads: "BOOL_stdcall Rectangle(HDC hdc, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) Error: function "Rectangle" is not a type name"

Comment: Use one of `typename`, `struct` and `class` for disambiguation before `Rectangle`.

Comment: Oh, so the `Rectangle` you get is from `windows.h`! Yes, use a `class Rectangle`

Comment: @user3786266: Please write **all** your include lines into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Carpet{
private:
    double pricePerSqYd;
    class Rectangle size;
```

`class Rectangle` will make the compiler understand that you mean your class's name and not "Windows function to draw a rectangle using a device context"

It is a good practice to use namespaces to avoid name collisions. Or, alternatively, use a convention like "prepend a class name with a **C**", i.e. `class CRectangle{...` and then it won't collide with a similar function's name

Comment: Thank you!, this worked it doesn't do this in the text book I don't know how they didn't get an error.

Comment: @user3786266: Simple, they didn't have a function declaration using the same name in scope too.

Comment: `BOOL_stdcall Rectangle(HDC hdc, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` was a give-away that the name had a collision with Windows's function

Answer (score 0):

Using this very simple driver code:

```
#include "CarpetClass.h"

int main()
{
    Carpet c;
}
```

the code compiles cleanly under Linux using gcc, but *only* if I fix the member function:

```
double getTotalPrice(){
    return (size.getArea()*pricePerSqYd);
}
```

Have you made sure that you aren't including anything else that defines a `Rectangle`?  You might also want to insert some `#include` guards in your headers, and provide default constructors and destructors.

To ask a better question, next time try cutting and pasting the code (and the error message!) directly from your computer to avoid time-wasting typos.