# What does this class declaration mean?

Tags: c++, class, types, header-files

Came across a snippet that I'm not sure how to interpret, in a header file:

```
...
private:
    class Ellipsoid * ellipse;
```

It's later initialized in the cpp:

```
ellipse = (Ellipsoid *) something->GetEllipse();
```

The class keyword on this data member is throwing me off. Is this a pointer to a class/type that inherits from Ellipsoid? Thus, is "ellipse" to be treated like a reference to a type?

Comment: It's more of a C-ism.

Comment: Putting the keyword `class` in front of a class name (for declaring variables, members, parameters, etc.) is optional in C++. (Same holds for `struct`.) You typically don't use it in C++, while in C it is required (which of course only holds for `struct` since `class` is added in C++).

Comment: @leemes unless there is something else called `Ellipsoid`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Can you give an example of such an allowed name clash (in C++)?

Comment: @leemes: As it happens, since you asked for an example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496855/nesting-an-object-in-a-class) was asked a few minutes ago...

Comment: @djikay Thank you for the hint, I've learnt something new again. I'd never put `class` there anyways, since what I want to tell C++ is that it is a `typename`, not that it is a `class`. But maybe I'm simply used to put `typename` a lot in front of types when meta-programming. ;)

Comment: Anyways, the argument in the accepted answer is stronger in my opinion, as in that case, `typename` obviously wouldn't work as a replacement for `class`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `class` keyword used there simply *declares* the symbol `Ellipsoid` to be a `class` at the site of its usage.

If the compiler already knows that symbol to be a class, it's optional.

```
class Ellipsoid;

class MyClass
{
    private:
        /*class*/ Ellipsoid * ellipse;
};
```

However, the usage you show will prevent compiler errors if the symbol is as-yet undeclared.

```
//class Ellipsoid;

class MyClass
{
    private:
        class Ellipsoid * ellipse;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense now.